# .NET Core service discovery with IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am still a bit confused in Microsoft's strategy on how to deploy .NET Core Kestrel. Apparently the recommended way would be an IIS as reverse-proxy on a VM and on the same host one or several Kestrel instances? To my understanding IIS cannot even deploy Kestrel's on multiple VMs:s, making it even mover confusing.

Anyway, if we were to go with IIS and somehow deploy Kestrels on a large set of VM:s, would it be possible to use some service discovery capability, together with IIS specifically? In other scenarios e.g. Interlock+NGINX, or Consul+HAProxy would be possible, but I'm trying to figure out the Microsoft way of doing things.

Comment: You don't need any VMs at all, when you host it in IIS. You just host it like any other ASP.NET application. Only difference is, ASP.NET Core application runs outside of IIS process and is not tied to the App pool. There isn't any easy way to do service discovery with ASP.NET Core and IIS. If you run ASP.NET Core on full .NET Framework, you can use Service Fabric for automatic scale-out and service discovery. You lose .NET Core and portability (except of mono), at least for now

Comment: There is however Microphone (https://github.com/rogeralsing/Microphone) for a more classical microservice/service discovery approach, which runs with consul or etcd in the background, the resolving happens within the application and not in the server though so for IIS you'd still need a "front-end" application which takes the requests then decides where to route it internally

Comment: Thanks for both. We actually go with ASP.NET Core and .NET Core instead of full framework, although the switch shouldn't bee to large from core to full. Regarding Service Fabric, can it run both UI rendering and RESTful WEBApi applications? We use ASP.NET Core for both UI and services. If Service Fabric can host both, then that's interesting.

Comment: Yes, but its a bit different approach (see http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-add-a-web-frontend/ and http://https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-quick-start/). You have reliable or statefull services and web applications. From your web application you call the services (via interface and proxy). The services are internally addressed with uri like `fabric:/MyApplication/MyService`, so once you go with this approach you won't be able to switch easily if you change your mind later on

Comment: Very informative, thanks Tseng :)